PostGIS, Node.js, Express.js => OpenLayers from localhost to server
New to Node.js I try to build up an api to display data from PostGIS in OpenLayers.
In my development environment this works fine using Node / Express to deliver GeoJSON on localhost:3000. The OpenLayers-frontend loads the layers from the routes defined in Express.
in backend:
import express from 'express';
import pg from 'pg';
import cors from 'cors';
import dbConfig from './dbConfig.cjs';

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

// Middleware for CORS
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

// Configuration of the database connection
const { Pool } = pg;
const pool = new Pool(dbConfig);


// Route to get data out of the database
app.get('/data/parzellen', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const sql2 = "SELECT jsonb_build_object('type','FeatureCollection', 'features', jsonb_agg(feature)) FROM (SELECT jsonb_build_object('type','Feature','id',id,'geometry',ST_AsGeoJSON(st_transform(the_geom,4326))::jsonb,'properties', to_jsonb(row) - 'the_geom') AS feature FROM (SELECT * FROM parzellen p where st_intersects(st_transform(the_geom,4326),ST_MakeEnvelope(" + req.query.bbox + "))) row) features;";
    const result2 = await pool.query(sql2);
    res.json(result2.rows[0].jsonb_build_object);

  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error! Could not retrieve any data:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
  }
});

// Middleware to register requests
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log(`Request: ${req.method} ${req.url} am ${new Date()}`);
  next(); // Calls the function next() to pass the request to the next middleware
});

// Route to handle all other requests
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.status(404).send('The site does not exist');
  });

// Initialize the server
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Express-Server is listening on port ${port}`);
  });

in OpenLayers frontend:
...
    
var parzellen = new VectorLayer({
        title: 'Parzellen',
        visible: false,
        minZoom: 12,
        source: new VectorSource({
            format: new GeoJSON(),
            url: function (extent) {
                return (
                    'http://localhost:3000/data/parzellen' +
                    '?bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',4326'
                );
            },
            strategy: bboxStrategy,
        }),
        style: {
            'stroke-color': 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8)',
            'stroke-width': 2,
            'fill-color': 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1)',
        }
    });

...

When doing a build from my frontend, and upload the dist-folder to my server (https://myserver.com/dist), the map displays fine. Only the layers loaded from the database are not displayed.
The backend-architecture (Express, node-postgres and Cors) is on the same server as the frontend and the Express-server runs via 'node server.js' it tels me that 'Express-Server is listening on port 3000', but the frontend cannot acces the data. The port 3000 is opened on the server.
I've tried changing the address in frontend to:
'https://myserver.com:3000/data/parzellen' +

or
'https://myserver.com:3000/dist/data/parzellen' +

but I get an Error: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG
and
Cross-source (cross-origin) request blocked:
How can I solve this?
What would be the right addres in the frontend to fetch the data from the Express-server?
What else need to be configured to avoid the Cross-source errors?
Most tutorials,l that I've consulted are limited to the development part on localhost, but do not explain the next step, to get it running on a real server.
Could someone point me in the right direction?

This is more of an IT question on how computer network addressing works than a GIS- centric one. Examples use localhost because of the can of worms introduced by real IPs.
